# How to look for a specific value in .plist and then retrieve matches

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

As the title suggests, my .plist file is in this format - I don't know how to mark it up well for you to read. Stackoverflow doesn't understand the format.

```
root (array)
         Item 0 - Dict
                numberOfPerson String
                recipeName  String
                recipeIngredients String
          Item 1 -Dict
                NumberOfPerson String
...
```

I have a textfield for user and user will enter a couple of strings.

I want to look for matches with input and recipeIngredients of each item.

And when it is found I want to go to that cell in my tableview which i implemented.

how can I accomplish this.

These are what I have tried so far

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recipes" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *arrayOfPlist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

This turned out useless I can not use objectForKey

```
 for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {

           recipeIngredientsArray = [[arrayOfPlist objectAtIndex:i]                      objectForKey:@"recipeIngredients"];

}
```

This didn't help me either I can not maintain a good isequl method

Thanks for the help.

Comment: afaict... `NSString *strCurrentRecipeName = [[arrayOfPlist objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"recipeName"];` will give you the `recipeName` (_i know that this doesn't really answer the question... which... is why it's a comment_)

Comment: `recipeIngredientsArray = [[arrayOfPlist objectAtIndex:i]` makes no sense, since the object at index `i` is a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: @matt well i managed to get all the recipes ingredients with that mini loop. COuldnt use it for later but it made sense buddy

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of dictionaries that you want to filter. Look at using `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`. Run this on the array and test the passed dictionary to check the value of the `recipeIngredients` value.

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [arrayOfPlist indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL (NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj[@"recipeIngredients"] rangeOfString:input options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound;
}];
```

Then you can use `indexes` to see if you have any matches and to display them. Or, you could just use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` to filter the array directly:

```
NSArray *results = [arrayOfPlist filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recipeIngredients CONTAINS[cd] %@", input]];
```

and then show only the filtered results in the table view.

Comment: what kind of thing is that. Are you sure with those curly brackets and the others?

Comment: Good chance I got the syntax wrong as typed in a browser. Let me check block syntax...

Comment: Missed the block return type.